# How do I redirect to root - public/index.html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, redirect, root

I wish to do a redirection to index.html in my application/public folder.

```
def get_current_user
   @current_user = current_user
   if @current_user.nil?  
      redirect_to root_path
   end 
end
```

How do I achieve this ?

I haven't modified the root in my routes.rb ( Its still commented )

```
 # root :to => "welcome#index"
```

I get an error saying root_path is undefined.

How do I modify routes.rb so that root_path points to public/index.html ?

Comment: Instead of using `root_path`, use `redirect_to '/'`

Comment: @meagar It's answer, not comment, so why don't you just create your answer instead of commenting on question?

Comment: @MBO It is not an answer. The question was "How do I do X?" and my comment was "Don't, do Y instead". This is not an acceptable answer IMO, and I would downvote others for posting it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not Rails compatible.

Rails is MVC, C for controller, V for view.

So its internals need both.

Ok, `public/index.html` is displayed by default but it's just because process is bypassed.

So, you could create a `static` controller with an `index` action and it's corresponding view (just copy/paste the content of your current `public/index.html`file in it).

Then set:

```
root :to => "static#index"
```

And please, remove the `public/index.html` file :)

Comment: Rails supports serving static content from the `public` directory. This is completely "Rails compatible".

Comment: @apneadiving Rails comes with a static `public/index.html` out of the box for every single new project, and it works pretty well. You might as well tell him he **must** touch the database or else he isn't using the 'M' in 'MVC'.

Comment: Also "Rails is MVC, C for controller, V for view. So its internals need both" is completely false. Every time you do a `redirect_to` you're not using the "V" in MVC.

Comment: @meagar I'm new to Rails (and MVC in general), so could you explain more why a `redirect_to` means we're not using the 'V' ? I don't get that. If that requires a new question for a long answer, tell me, I'll create it!

Comment: @Lucas There is no *View* involved when you call `redirect_to` from a controller's action.

Answer (score 31):

You can assign a named route to a static file by passing any non-empty string as `:controller` and the path to the file as the `:action` for the route:

```
Application.routes.draw do

  root :controller => 'static', :action => '/' 
  # or
  # root :controller => 'static', :action => '/public/index.html'

end

# elsewhere

redirect_to root_path # redirect to /
```

Assuming you have a `public/index.html`, this is what will be served.

Comment: doing this also means that the view served has nothing to do with the other views in the app which is really unlikely. Views have a common layout, that's the beauty of Rails DRYness.

Comment: @apneadiving Doing so implies a lot more than just the lack of a shared layout, but there is nothing wrong with that. If you intend to serve a static index file then presumably you have decided there is *not* a common layout, and there is absolutely no reason not to serve `index.html` in this way.

Comment: @meagar Totally. Actually, IMO it is a choice between _shared layout_ (MVC) and _quick response_ (static files). Rails supports both, the beauty of Rails flexibility. (In MVC case I can still use the CSS to keep a somewhat shared look.)

Answer (score 9):

on controller

```
 redirect_to root_path ## (will redirect to root '/')
```

Answer (score 4):

route file:

```
     root 'main#index'
```

controller:

```
     class MainController < ApplicationController
       def index
         redirect_to '/index.html'
       end
     end
```

and using rails 4 controller action live this can behave like a single page application using the M & C with a twist on the V

Comment: You actually don't even need to define the `def index` action. Only defining the controller and index file is enough. Rails will skip the action in the route, if it is not found.

Answer (score 1):

**routes.rb**

```
...
root to: redirect('public/index.html')
...
```

This will redirect all request to `'/'`, to `'public/index.html'`.