# Rails: New user is not being created and when being redirected, Chrome says 'No Data Received'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Every time I submit the form, I get redirected to /users and Chrome is consistently giving me an error that says 'No Data Received' consistently.  I have tried commenting out all of the validation stuff but I get the exact same problem.  I would normally just keep debugging it myself but the lack of rails error message on the redirect has me stuck.

Here is my users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def index
  @users = User.all
end

def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    flash[:notice] = "You Signed up successfully"
    flash[:color]= "valid"
    redirect_to '/'
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
    flash[:color]= "invalid"
    redirect_to 'new'
  end
end

private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password)
    end
end
```

Here is my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
             format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
             uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 } 
end
```

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 30px">
            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :password %>
            <%= f.password_field :password_digest, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
            <%= f.label :first_name %>
            <%= f.search_field :first_name, class: 'form-control' %>
            <%= f.label :last_name %>
            <%= f.search_field :last_name, class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= f.submit "Create an Account", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT: I have also tried having the redirect in UsersController#create point to '/users' and I get the same 'No Data Received' error.  In the routes.rb, I have it set to
    resources :users
and I have static html in the index.html.erb file.  I can access it by directly going to /users.

Also, I'm less worried about the redirect issue and more worried about the lack of users being created.

EDIT 2: I can successfully create a user by seeding the database but I still can't create one with the form

Comment: Check the log file; there might be more details about what is happening. I am suspecting `redirect_to '/'` is causing this behavior because of the `root` route not being configured. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6257744/429758 for the root path configuration.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of messing around and staying up way past my bed time, I can say that I conquered.

I forgot to put :password_confirmation in the .permit section of user_params in the controller.  Now it reads:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Although I am still curious about the chrome error